# How to select a row at a time with Python and SQlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, row

I am working with an enrollment system using SQLite3 in Python. I am having a problem when I want to search for an speciffic student when I just have his first name. For example, I may have Gabriel Machado and Gabriel McPython in my "students" table.
When I use select from this table with just "Gabriel" as a parameter it will return to me 2 rows, one with each Gabriel, but my GUI only supports to show one "Gabriel" at a time. So what I want is, every time I click on the "serch" button, it will return me the next "Gabriel" on my list.

When I try:

```
dado = c.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE SQnome LIKE ?", ('%'+self.texNome.text()+'%',))
    for row in dado:
        print (row[1]) #Shows only the Full name for debugging
```

It will print me both "Gabriel Machado" and "Gabriel McPython". When what I actually want is:

1. Click Search Button, it will show me the first Gabriel
2. Click Search Button again, it will show me the second Gabriel.

I hope I made it clear, this is my first question here.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think `c.fetchone()` will get you what you want:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE SQnome LIKE ?", ('%'+self.texNome.text()+'%',))
```

Now each time the Search Button is clicked, you would call `c.fetchone()` and it will fetch you one row and then you could do this for example:

```
print(c.fetchone())
```